# How to rotate a line in a circle (radar like) in Processing while also plotting points?

Tags: rotation, line, processing

I am trying to rotate a line around in a circle that represents the direction a sensor is facing, while also plotting distance measurements. So I can't use background() in the draw function to clear the screen, because it erases the plotting of the distance readings. I've tried pggraphics and a few others ways, but can't seem to find a way to do it.

This is what I have right now:

```
 void setup() {
   background(255,255,255);
   size(540, 540);
 }

 void draw() {
   translate(width/2, height/2); 
   ellipse(0,0,100,100);
   newX = x*cos(theta)- y*sin(theta);
   newY = x*sin(theta)+ y*cos(theta);

   theta = theta + PI/100;
   //pushMatrix();
   fill(255, 255);
   line(0, 0, newX, newY);
   rotate(theta);
   //popMatrix(); 
 }
```

I am new to Processing, and coding in general, but can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do this? Thanks

This is what it outputs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CH66.jpg

Comment: what is the result of the above?

Comment: I just posted the output, but it is a line that rotates around, with a ellipse in the middle. As you can see, the line doesn't show up in the ellipse, but that is because it is drawing on top of the old line, so if I expand it to the whole screen, it would end up covering the plotted points too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use background(). You just need to redraw the readings on each frame. You could store the readings in an ArrayList, which allows you to add new readings, change them and remove them.

An example:

```java
ArrayList<PVector> readings;
int readingsCount = 15;
void setup() {
  size(540, 540);

  // create collection of random readings
  readings = new ArrayList<PVector>();
  for(float angle = 0; angle < TWO_PI; angle += TWO_PI/ readingsCount) {
    float distance = random(100, 200);
    // the new reading has an angle...
    PVector newReading = PVector.fromAngle(angle);
    // ... and a distance
    newReading.mult(distance);
    // Add the new reading to the collection
    readings.add(newReading);
  }
}
void draw() {
  background(255);

  // Put (0, 0) in the middle of the screen
  translate(width/2, height/2);

  float radius = 250;
  noFill();
  ellipse(0, 0, 2*radius, 2*radius);

  // draw spinning line
  float angle = frameCount * 0.1;
  line(0, 0, radius * cos(angle), radius * sin(angle));

  // draw readings
  for(PVector p : readings) {
    ellipse(p.x, p.y, 20, 20);
  }
}
```